# How to use the Tag description as the title attribute?

Tags: tags

I'm trying to use tags to create a list of cross references for each post and want the tag description to show next to the tag and/or as the title attribute for the hyperlink so the description shows when a visitor holds the cursor over the link.

Using the TwentyTen theme I have located the code in functions.php and amended it as below:

```
function twentyten_posted_in() {
    // Retrieves tag list of current post, separated by commas.
    $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( $before = '<br /> <br />' , $sep = ' here'.'<br /><br />' , $after = '<br />' );
    if ( $tag_list ) {
        $posted_in = __( 'Cross Reference %2$s. ', 'twentyten' );
    } 


    // Prints the string, replacing the placeholders.
    printf(
        $posted_in,
        get_the_category_list( ',  ' ),
        $tag_list,
                get_permalink(),
        the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' )
    );
}
endif;
```

As you can see I've changed the heading to say Cross Reference and by adding breaks I have a list of tags rather than a paragraph.  I've identified where I want the Tag Description to go with the word "here".

I thought it would be as simple as adding tag_description() but that didn't work.  If I put a number in the brackets, e.g. tag_description(5) it displays the tag description in the correct place, but of course all the tags have the wrong description.

Help!

Thanks
Ian.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) and create a custom array:

```
function wpse_31396_terms_with_desc( $post_id = NULL, $taxonomy = 'post_tag' )
{
    NULL === $post_id && $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( empty ( $post_id ) )
    {
        return '';
    }

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );

    if ( empty ( $terms ) )
    {
        return '';
    }

    $list = array ();


    foreach ( $terms as $term )
    {
        $list[ $term->term_id ] = array(
            'url' => get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ),
            'name' => $term->name,
            'description' => $term->description
        );
    }

    return $list;
}
```

Sample usage for the `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_31396_add_terms_with_desc' );

function wpse_31396_add_terms_with_desc( $content )
{
    $tags = wpse_31396_terms_with_desc();

    if ( '' === $tags )
    {
        return $content;
    }

    $taglist = '<h2>Cross Reference</h2><ul class="taglist-with-desc">';
    foreach ( $tags as $tag )
    {
        $desc = empty ( $tag['description'] )
            ? '' : '<div class="tagdesc">' . wpautop( $tag['description'] ) . '</div>';
        $taglist .= sprintf(
            '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>%3$s</li>',
            $tag['url'],
            $tag['name'],
            $desc
        );
    }

    return $content . $taglist . '</ul>';
}
```

[image]